# Crear rama local desde pull request en github

Tags: git, github

un compañero ha creado una pull request en github desde una rama que tenía en su local.

Yo necesito bajarme esta rama a mi local para probarla antes de mergear a develop.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien, tu compañero ha hecho un pull request y ahora en github tenéis un rama remota.

Debes usar un checkout con la opción --track y la rama remota para hacer el seguimiento de esta.

Aquí viene mejor explicado.

https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/checkout-remote-branch/

Saludos,

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

ya @jctalavan dio una respuesta (a la que incluso le hice upvote) pero quiero dejar constancia de un feature adicional que nos brinda *github*. github permite tener acceso a las ramas *de los PRs*, sin necesidad de saber a qué rama está asociado un PR.

Agregando una línea a la definición de un remote, se puede hacer que git cree ramas **numeradas** (según el número del PR). Asumiendo que el remote se llama `origin`, se **agrega** una línea como esta a la definición del remote en `.git/config`:

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

De esta forma, cuando se hace `git fetch`, cada PR queda automágicamente registrado en nuestro local por el número del PR:

```
$ git fetch origin
From github.com:blah/blah
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/1/head -> origin/pr/1
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/2/head -> origin/pr/2
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/3/head -> origin/pr/3
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/4/head -> origin/pr/4
```

Y así con solo el número del PR podemos trabajar con la rama.

Y ahora si quiero hacer checkout de la rama de un pr: `git checkout origin/pr/3` (o `git checkout pr/3` si queremos crear una rama local).

Referencia: https://medium.com/easyread/today-i-learned-checkout-to-pull-request-in-github-public-repository-8b3562f168b2